# ajax post opens a window with blanked url

Tags: javascript

I have this Ajax post method which opens new window with data fine, but in URL field of a new window always stands about:blank. I want specific url to be written in url field.

```
$("#test").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
        url: host+"/test",
        type: 'POST',
        data:{
            "home":$(".testing_home").data('home')
        },
        success:function(response){
            //console.log(response)
            var x = window.open(host+'/testing');
            x.document.open();
            x.document.write(response);
        },
        error:function(e){
            console.log(e);
        }
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new window will show the URL of the document loaded into it.

While you specify a URL to visit when you call `window.open`, you immediately cancel navigation to it by writing a new document with `document.write`.

If you want to show the URL being visited, then you need to actually visit that URL.

This could probably be achieved by:

- Getting rid of the JavaScript
- Moving the data from a `data-home` attribute to a hidden input's value
- Opening the window by submitting a form with `target="_blank"`.

Answer (score -1):

Focus element will help you to achieve this task.

All you need is:

```
var x = window.open('/test.html', '_blank');
x.focus();
```

Comment: you don't need to use host if you want to open a page that's on the same domain

Comment: This is just plain wrong. A new window / tab is the default behaviour when the second argument is omitted.

Comment: This doesn't address the question at all (which is about the URL displayed in the address bar)

Comment: does your answer solve the OP's problem? Look at that first

Comment: That just means that the OP hasn't recognised it as the best solution (and since their profile suggests they haven't even visited the site since they asked the question, it would be hard for them to do so), not that it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: yes i believe it does not solve the problem, any problem? you did not even provide the code for OP's question to work how can you say your solution is working

Comment: I didn't ask what you believe. I know my answer solves the problem. While yours can be [trivially demonstrated](https://jsbin.com/lutahiromi/1/edit?html,js,output) to [not solve the problem](https://i.imgur.com/9MoI3R2.gif)

Comment: You threw away the `x.document.write(response);` which is the significant part of the question.

Comment: Yes, they did. (a) They said in the first paragraph "Ajax post method which opens new window with data" and (b) The code they have has `x.document.write(response);` and if you remove that then the code does nothing with the response at all which makes the entire Ajax request pointless.

Comment: Quentin is correct. I used Ajax to get the data from the server.

Comment: I want to send a data by post to the server and return a html template opening in new window